# From Google SSO to normal account

Tags: support, accounts

When I signed in for the first time in Stack Overflow, I decided to do it with my Google Account. In other words, instead of creating an account with a username and a password, I used the Single sign-on.

This works well in my private devices, but I never login with my Google Account into my work station, what keeps me "out" of the community when browsing Stack Overflow from my working environment.

Is it possible to "move" my account to sign-in with a password and email? (I'll use 2FA anyway).

I can log in into Stack Overflow and later log out from Google, but I'm considering an independent account.

Comment: On [My Logins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/current), you should be able to add a Stack Exchange (email+password) credential.

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed "the correct answer" :-)

Comment: StakOverflow was a new one, [the 89th](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#Stack_Overflow).